# I want to retrieve the email or username data entered for password reset, but failed. how can I do it?

Tags: php, forms

I want to see the data(email or username) typed in the lost password form. I studied many functions but couldn't find how to do it.

My goal is to provide a restriction or find out what data has been entered via e-mail. I don't know how to pull data. After I get the data, I'll take care of the rest. What function can I use?

Comment: Do you mean everything typed into the form, whether it matches an existing user or not? I don't think that's doable, no - if you look at retrieve_password() in wp-login.php then you can see that the first hook is after it's looked up the user. I'd guess mu-plugins are loaded for wp-login though so you might be able to put something in there spots this is a retrieve_password request and does the log there though.

Comment: Or if you just want to know which users have had password resets requested you can hook lostpassword_post.

Comment: @Rup Right now, I can find out which user has sent password reset request with the $password_reset_key function. I'll do a few more things now. Thank you. :)

Comment: What are you trying to implement that requires this? I've read your question a few times and could not understand what you wanted, some context would help figure that out

Comment: Thanks Tom. A few days ago I fixed the problem. No problem right now.